# Pymongo package could not be installed

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to install the pymongo package using the command pip install pymongo and it displays the message 'DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (3.9.0)'
Could you please suggest any solution so i can install this package ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the package is already satisfied

Can you check this folder

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo
```

Comment: Yes i checked this path and the package exist but when I try to establish the connection to MongoDB using the below code : import pymongo from pymongo import MongoClient .. it displays the error : import pymongo ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'pymongo'

Comment: Do you have python 3 installed?

Comment: Yes I have Python 3 installed

Comment: Do you want to use python 3?

Comment: Yes, should i uninstall Python 2.7 or what to do exactly ?

Comment: You need to change your environment variable. I will post the solution

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to change the environment variable like here:

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931468/11079758

Windows 10

1. Type "System" into the search bar to go to system settings in the control panel (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System)
2. Click "Advanced System Settings" -> 2Environment Variables2

For User Variables:

3. Highlight the row for "Path" by clicking on it and then click the "Edit" button
4. Highlight by clicking the version of python you want to remove from your environment variables and then click the "Delete" button.

Repeat steps 3 and 4 for System Environment Variables.

5. Close all the windows by clicking the "Ok" buttons
6. Restart your machine